# Why does my page jump around so much?

Tags: javascript, css, image, scroll

I'm very confused with my current webpage: http://armandbakx.nl/ - (adjusted it, I'm not here for self-promotion).

The idea is that I have a couple of images on my page, which are clickable. Once clicked a scrollable container should pop up, showing more information and images.

So far, with the help of some great people here, I've managed to make the JavaScript work. The only problems I'm running into right now are that when I click an image, the entire 'back-page' shifts. I'm not sure what's causing this, and even more unsure how to solve it.

Secondly, when an image is clicked and the scrollable container 'hovers' over the main page, it seems that other images still respond to clicking.. I've already hammered the z-index up to ridiculous amounts but it still does this. I don't think this is a JavaScript issue, but can't fathom what causes this in the css.

Thirdly, when an .img is clicked, and you scroll through the content of the scrollable container, when you click back towards the main page, it often also ends up scrolled upwards or downwards. How do I prevent this from happening?

I hope it's somewhat comprehensible and I hope someone is willing to help me.
I have a codepen here with everything this page runs on at the moment, except for the images.
[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NGjabQ)

```
$('img').on('click', show);
$('.overlay').on('click', hide);

function show(){   
   $('.scroll-container').eq($(this).parent().index()).addClass('show');
   $('.content-container').addClass('no-scroll');
   $('.overlay').addClass('opacity');
}

function hide() {
   $('.scroll-container').removeClass('show');
   $('.content-container').removeClass('no-scroll');
   $('.overlay').removeClass('opacity');
}
```

Comment: What browser are you using? I can't replicate your experience in the first two questions.

Comment: I'm using Chrome, what happens with you?

Comment: Chrome, when I use the link you gave and click a red box, the overlay $(.overlay.opacity) blocks the screen so I can't click the boxes underneath. When I click the overlay, it goes away and then I can click the boxes. This seems like the intended behavior. Also, clicking the boxes does not cause the page to jump around for me. The only issue to me is the third one, which is that scroll the pop-up content scrolls the whole page

Comment: Is it just an overlay you're seeing? What's supposed to happen is that when you click one of the red boxes a scroll-container should appear (show/hide).
Inside this container there's some content (Lorem ipsum and an image in this case).

When this scroll-container and overlay are active, all the other red boxes change position, I don't understand what's causing this.

Comment: I see an overlay with the content, exactly as it sounds like you are intending. The boxes are not visible when the overlay is active. The red boxes don't change position unless I scroll.

Comment: That's the point. I don't want the boxes to move. When the scroll-container and the overlay are active, all the other small red squares move. They should remain in the same position as before the click. That was the first problem. Do you see what's causing this? Am I missing something?

Comment: It's one of the problems.

Explaining what I want might be simpler:
Clickable boxes with working overlay and scrollable container with content.

The overlay and scrollable container work, but for me the boxes move somewhere when I click one of them. That's one problem.

The boxes also react to scrolling apparantly, which shouldn't happen. That's the second problem.

The images inside the scrollable container also seem to respond to clicking, which isn't what I want either. This is the third problem.

Comment: You aren't using a doctype, which puts you into "quirks mode". Try adding this to your very first line: <!DOCTYPE html> and tell us if that fixes anything. A doctype is required of all new web pages.

Comment: Applied <!DOCTYPE html> to the first line in my code, but it didn't do much.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to just answer your third question, and this approach might prevent the other issues as well.

Inside of your show function, make the keep track of the position the browser was in when the content opened. Then, in your hide function, return the browser to that position. This should prevent your boxes from moving around.

Here is an example. I wrapped everything in an immediately-invoked function to prevent the variables from being globals.

```
(function(){

var currentTop = 0;

$('img').on('click', show);
$('.overlay').on('click', hide);

function show(){  

    currentTop = $(window).scrollTop();

   $('.scroll-container').eq($(this).parent().index()).addClass('show');
   $('.content-container').addClass('no-scroll');
   $('.overlay').addClass('opacity');
}

function hide() {

    $(window).scrollTop(currentTop);

   $('.scroll-container').removeClass('show');
   $('.content-container').removeClass('no-scroll');
   $('.overlay').removeClass('opacity');
}


})();
```

Comment: Might have been worth stating that I'm absolutely worthless when it comes to JavaScript. I understand what you're suggesting, and hope it will also help fix the other issues, but I'm clueless as to how I track the position of the browser top and implement that in my code. Right now I copied your example to my .js, but it didn't result in much..